# laravel relationship one to one or one to many?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

**Table 1(users):**

```
id    username   password  role created_at updated_at

1      jhon        yz        1   sometime     sometime
```

**Table 2(role):**

```
id     role     created_at   updated_at

1    employee     sometime    sometime
```

**what I want**

```
id    username   password  role     created_at updated_at

1      jhon        yz     employee   sometime     sometime
```

**Users Model:**

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    public function role()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('role', 'id', 'role');
    }
    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');    
}
```

**Roles Model:**

```
class Role extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'roles'; 
}
```

how do i get the role name in the view ? Is my relationship right

Comment: It's `user belongsTo role`

Answer (score 0):

one role can be used by many users, like:

user1 can be admin
user2 can be admin too
user3 is a manager
user4 is a manager too

if thats the case then,..

Users Model:

```
    class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
        protected $table = 'users';
        protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');

        public function role()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo('Role');
        }
    }
```

Roles Model:

```
class Role extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'roles';

    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('User');
    }
}
```

then use:

```
User::with('role')->whereRole(1)->get(); // assuming that 1 = employee; this is eager loading
```

this will yield something like:

```
[
    new User([
       'id' => 1,
       'username' => 'blahblah',
       'password' => 'pass',
       'role' => 1,
       'created_at' => '0000-00-00',
       'updated_at' => '0000-00-00',
       'role' => new Role([
                    'id' => 1,
                    'role' => 'employee',
                    'created_at' => '0000-00-00',
                    'updated_at' => '0000-00-00'
                 ])
    ])
]
```

Comment: ok how do i fetch all the employee record for this $users = User::all()->role; ?

Comment: Try `foreach (User::with('role')->get() as $user)
{
    echo $user->role->role;
}`

Comment: if you want to have an output like the one you shown above, you can use transformers